# Will I benefit from using Spring Webflux in applciation where the rest of the components are non-reactive?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I want to introduce the new service in our company application which will ease some load of monolitic app. The specific of new service is that it will in scope of each request make a lot of http calls(simultaneously as well) and compose obtained data to make new calls. The question is: will I benefit from using Spring WebFlux here provided the rest of the services are synchronous(and backpressure I assume won't work)? Does it make sense at least in terms of resource consumption not to be blocking?

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer to your question without a practical knowledge of the problem. That said, if the existing services that your new service will interact with can handle the (sometimes weird) behavior of a reactive app, why not! Just make sure you're going full reactive stack on the new service; mixed mvc/reactive stacks in one app are full of unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Impossible to answer, we have no idea about the type of application, numbers of requests, hardware of system, etc etc. POC and benchmark. Voted to close.